# ReferenceError: handlebars is not defined

Tags: nodejs, express, handlebars.js

Estoy tratando de utilizar Handlebars, para llamar los datos en una vista, la cual utilizo llaves para traer los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estoy requiriendo el handlebars desde una ruta:**

const template = handlebars.compile("{{aString.trim}}");

**Aquí configuro el Handlebars:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

app.engine ('.hbs', exphbs({
defaultLayout: 'main',
layoutsDir: path.join (app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
partialsDir: path.join (app.get('views'), 'partials'),
extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set ('view engine', 'hbs');

**y al correr el servidor me sale este error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
C:\Users\Borbón\Documents\GitHub\Crud_Note\src\routes\notes.js:3
const template = handlebars.compile("{{aString.trim}}");
^

ReferenceError: handlebars is not defined
at Object. (C:\Users\Borbón\Documents\GitHub\Crud_Note\src\routes\notes.js:3:18)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\Borbón\Documents\GitHub\Crud_Note\src\index.js:37:9)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Muchas gracias, sus aportaciones serán de mucha ayuda...

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Una pregunta, ¿Estás utilizando `require` para usar handlebars?
 `const Handlebars = require("handlebars");`

Comment: @JonatanLavado. Por favor publica tu comentario como respuesta. Ese es el problema que presenta la traza.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer uso de [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/installation/), necesitas primero usar `require`.

```
const Handlebars = require("handlebars");
const template = Handlebars.compile("{{aString.trim}}");
```